# Passing Value from a UIView to UIVIewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In the iOS app I am building i am making sounds occur at particular time intervals.A ticker sound and another sound , this is done in a UIView called ResultView. Now this view is displayed by the ResultViewController.

PROBLEM:
 **When the back button from the navigation button is pressed i want the sounds to go off.**

This back button makes it go back to the viewController named LOBBY
This  is a problem as there is no viewWillDissapear function available.
The entire code is huge to put so i have put up only small snippets . Thanks in advance

ResultViewController:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
action:@selector(gotoLobby)];
```

// the lobby selector

```
- (void)gotoLobby{
     //Pop Back to Lobby
     [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];    
}
```

Now the view (PlayerResultView) where the sounds are being played:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.75 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"soundKey"])
            {
                NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                  pathForResource:@"ticker bell" ofType:@"caf"];
                NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
                AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)pathURL,&tickerbell);
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(tickerbell);
            }
}
```

Again :
i need a way to control these sounds to go off when the back button is pressed.(whenit goes to the lobby that is)

also since the bar is coded in, it does not show on the mainStoryBoard so please dont tell me to use the IBAction method. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution to this would be moving your sound code into the view controller. This would be more in line with the model-view-controller pattern.

In any case, you need to add in your `PlayerResultView` a method to stop playing the sound:

```
- (void)stopCurrentSound {
    OSStatus AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (tickerBell);
}
```

Then, in `gotoLobby`, you can call it:

```
- (void)gotoLobby{

  [self.playerResultView stopCurrentSound];

  //Pop Back to Lobby
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];    
}
```

I assume that you have a reference to the `PlayerResultView` view in your view controller, otherwise you need to add one so you can send messages to the view.

Comment: Hey i know about the MVC thing if i do move it into the viewcontroller , however the timing and syncing the sounds with the animations would be a problem right ?

Comment: syncing the sound with what animation? in any case, the MVC bit is just a remark -- in any cases you need do something similar to what I suggest -- only you would call into the view controller instead of into the view...